# django forms render static text

Tags: django, forms, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I am using django form wizard to render a series of forms and in my last screen, I want to show the user a simple screen that says `press the save button to continue`. So, this last screen has no input elements. I, of course, need it to be part of the wizard workflow. I was wondering if there is a `Form` element that can be used for something like this or if there is some hack to basically just show this text.

So basically I have something like:

```
class FinalForm(Forms.Form):
    text = Forms.CharField(label="Press Save to update the record")    

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(FinalForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.helper = FormHelper()  # crispy-forms bit
```

Here, of course, the `CharField` renders the text as a label and is an input field. Can it be done that we can have this form only contain some static text?

The `urls.py` is declared as:

```
url(r'^reviewrecord/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.ContactWizard.as_view([FirstForm, SecondForm, FinalForm]),
        name='reviewrecord'),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a form with static text! Just create an empty form (a form without any elements) and you can add the text to your html template.

To display the text *only* on the correct step of the form wizard (i.e the one displaying the empty form) you can use the step number as explained in the docs:

https://django-formtools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/wizard.html#creating-templates-for-the-forms